# Cannot read properties of undefined using Map in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to populate the data from my mock data which is in json format. When I am trying to run the component I am getting undefined reading map error. I have checked that my component is rendering with the value only. Even it's rendering with the value I am getting this undefined error. I have tried to applied conditional rendering but that doesn't help me. When I am trying to apply conditional rendering on **createCells** For Row, I am getting "**Reference Error**" Cell is not defined. "**CreateCellsForRow**" is making an issue I need to check whether it's getting an values or not if values are not there I need to return null. Could any one assist me what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
const createCell = cell => ({ key: cell.key, children: cell.title });

//Actual code
const createCellsForRow = cells => cells.map(cell => createCell(cell)); -----> I am getting error from here(undefined reading map)

//applied conditional Rendering(getting cells is not defined reference error)
const createCellsForRow = cells.length > 0 ? cells => cells.map(cell => createCell(cell)) : null

const StTable = () => {
  const [selectedKey, setSelectedKey] = useState([]);

  const handleRowToggle = (event, metaData) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (selectedKey !== metaData.key) {
      setSelectedKey(metaData.key);
    }
  };

  const createRow = rowData => (
    {
      key: rowData.key,
      cells: createCellsForRow(rowData.cells),
      toggleAction: {
        metaData: { key: rowData.key },
        onToggle: handleRowToggle,
        isToggled: selectedKey === rowData.key,
        toggleLabel: rowData.toggleText,
      },
    }
  );

  const createRows = data => data.map(childItem => createRow(childItem));

  return (
    <Table
      summaryId="example-single-select"
      summary="This table shows an implementation of single row selection."
      numberOfColumns={4}
      cellPaddingStyle="standard"
      rowStyle="toggle"
      dividerStyle="horizontal"
      headerData={{
        selectAllColumn: {
          checkLabel: 'Single Selection',
        },
        cells: [
          { key: 'cell-0', id: 'toggle-0', children: 'Name' },
          { key: 'cell-1', id: 'toggle-1', children: 'Address' },
          { key: 'cell-2', id: 'toggle-2', children: 'Phone Number' },
          { key: 'cell-3', id: 'toggle-3', children: 'Email Id' },
        ],
      }}
      bodyData={[
        {
          rows: createRows(mockData),
        },
      ]}
    />
  );
};

export default StTable;

//MockDataSample
[
{"SNO":001, "SregID":"SOO1", "Status": "Available"},
{"SNO":002, "SregID":"SOO2", "Status": "Not Available"},
{"SNO":003, "SregID":"SOO3", "Status": "Available"},
]
```

Comment: Seems straight forward; `mockData` where it is used in your component is not defined. Where is / should it be defined?

Comment: Either change Actual code to `(cells || []).map(yourcode)` or change conditional rendering to `createCellsForRow = cells => cells ? cells.map(yourcode) : null`. In your actual code you are directly calling map and it breaks because cells is undefined. And your changed code your trying to access the cells before passing the value to the function.

Comment: I think your mock data is missing `cells` property. The `rawdata.cells` parameter in the function createRow(). Make sure the `rawdata` contains a `cells array`. I suspect it doesn't exist and so calling map will result in error. From the mock data shown in your question, it doesn't exist.

Comment: Your `mockdata` sample doesn't contain any property named `cells`.  Either that mock data is wrong or you are missed something while posting here. Because the data you posted as sample does not have any of the properties you are trying to access

Answer (score -1):

You need to set `array && array.length>0` condition before every map function.
`array` check whether the array is available or not. (is array is not available then getting undefined)